# AngularJS, how to get domain from a cookie

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm trying to remove cookies from my browser when logging out, but I can't do that without specifying the domain when removing.

```
$cookies.remove('Name',{domain:'.test123.com'});
```

I want to automate the process by getting all the cookies and removing them, since the domain of each cookie changes we need to specify the domain when removing. But i don't see any way how to get the domain.

```
 angular.forEach(cookies, function (v, k) {
    $cookies.remove(k);
});
```

Since, I'm not setting the domain and the cookies take the domain automatically, How do i get the domain for each cookie.

Comment: how did you save the cookie ???

Comment: $cookies.put('Name','Tom');

Comment: you want to delete the cookies that you set from your website ??

Comment: Yes and those coming from server. I'm able to delete them using $cookies.remove('Name',{domain:'.test123.com'}); , where i have to manually input the domain name. I want to know whether there's a way to get the domain name of each cookie.

Comment: check out my answer mark as accepted if this helped :)

Answer (score 1):

`$cookies.getAll()` will give you all the keys for cookies you can use that to delete all. See  details [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

```
var cookies = $cookies.getAll();
angular.forEach(cookies, function (v, k) {
    $cookies.remove(k,[domain]);
});
```

Comment: I'm only getting the cookie name and value. Not getting the domain of the cookie.

Comment: add the domain  to delete only cookies from your domain

Comment: I have cookies from different domain and i want to delete them all. So, giving them manually is a huge process. And to remove it, the syntax is,        $cookies.remove('Name',{domain:'.test123.com'});

Comment: Now keep those domain name on a list .... then loop through that as well this would make it more visible

Comment: yeah, that's one way to do it, but is there any way to get the domain name automatically when we are getting the cookie.